# Saving a .xml file in Java

Tags: java, spring-ws

I am using WebServiceTemplate class and I am storing the XML response that I receive from the webservice in a file. But the .xml file for some reason contains all the `<`, `>` saved as `;&lt` and `;&gt`.

Is there any way I can convert this to a proper `.xml` file before saving it?

```
        InputStream inputStream = new   WebServiceClientImpl().getClass().getResourceAsStream("Request.xml");
        StreamSource source = new StreamSource(inputStream2);
        StreamResult result = new StreamResult(new File("Response.xml"));               
        webServiceTemplate.sendSourceAndReceiveToResult(defaultURI,source, result);
```

request.xml :

```
 <list>
 <requestXmlString xs:type="type:string" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2000/XMLSchema- instance">
 <![CDATA[<request operationName="list" locale="en">
     <resourceDescriptor name="" wsType="folder" uriString="/" isNew="false">
     <label>null</label>
     </resourceDescriptor>           
     </request>]]>
      </requestXmlString>
 </list>
```

Response.xml

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><listResponse   xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"   soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"><listReturn   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="xsd:string">&lt;?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?&gt;
    &lt;operationResult version="2.0.1"&gt;
&lt;returnCode&gt;&lt;![CDATA[0]]&gt;&lt;/returnCode&gt;
&lt;resourceDescriptor name="Record1" wsType="reportUnit"  uriString="/xyz" isNew="false"&gt;
    &lt;label&gt;&lt;![RECORD 1]]&gt;&lt;/label&gt;
    &lt;creationDate&gt;1338285680000&lt;/creationDate&gt;
    &lt;resourceProperty name="PROP_RESOURCE_TYPE"&gt;
        &lt;value&gt;&lt;!
```

Comment: @Brian I've added some snippets of my code. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

While writing into the file, characters like < > & are serialised so that they can later be read by the XML parser.

You can try using CDATA encoding on the text node. In this case, you will have the < inside a CDATA block.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CDATA

Comment: Thanks. I've added my code.The problem is I need to unmarshal the XML response that I get. I am thinking of using Castor Unmarshaller to bind the XML to my java object. But it doesn't seem to recognize these characters ;&lt in the file. I am not sure if it even recognizes CDATA section. I will post my request and response XML so you can have a look.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out! :) There are libraries that do this. So a simple

```
StringEscapeUtils.unescapeXml(xml)
```

will do the trick!

Comment: What you had before *was* proper XML. The problem is the XML contains nested XML as a String. Using unescapeXml on the string will change it to something else.